# VBA - MS ACCESS to external SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a problem with this instruction in VBA that tries to import data from an external SQL Server DB into a local MS Access DB:

```
Conectar = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\VENTAS\VENTAS.mdb;" _
            & "Persist Security Info=False;"

cn.ConnectionString = Conectar    
cn.Open

SQL= "insert into PRO (COD_PRO,DESC_PRO) " & _
     "select COD_ARTICU,DESCRIPCIO  " & _
     "FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=VAIO\SQLEXPRESS;User" & _ 
     "ID=XXX;Password=XXX;').ACPE.dbo.STA11 where perfil<>'N';"

cn.Execute Sql
```

The error

> "Syntax error in FROM clases"

It seems that I can't use `OPENDATASOUCE` to an SQL Server from Access?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reverse the query reference. `OPENDATASOURCE` is a SQL Server TSQL command and is not an MS Access SQL command. Consider running an ODBC inline of a stored query:

**SQL** *(save as stored query or script as VBA string)*

```sql
INSERT INTO PRO (COD_PRO, DESC_PRO) 
SELECT COD_ARTICU, DESCRIPCIO
FROM [ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};server=VAIO\SQLEXPRESS;database=ACPE;UID=XX;PWD=XXXX].STA11;
```

**VBA**

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryName"
' OR CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Alternatively, create a linked table, then run the append query as linked tables can interact with local tables:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
      "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};server=VAIO\SQLEXPRESS;database=ACPE;UID=XX;PWD=XXXX;", _
       acTable, "STA11", "STA11"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO PRO (COD_PRO, DESC_PRO) 
          SELECT COD_ARTICU, DESCRIPCIO
          FROM STA11;"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

OPENDATASOURCE is T-Sql statement and is used from within SQL Server not from Access, so you get this error.

To insert data from PRO table which is located in sql server you can:

Create a linked table in VENTAS.mdb to Sql server table "PRO"

Or

create pass through query to Sql Server Pro table in  VENTAS.mdb.

Comment: Would a pass-through query recognize the tables in the local Access database?

Comment: @Zev, yes, pass-through query can access any ODBC connection, including odbc to acess database. In the OP you create pass through query in VENTAS.mdb  to SQL server.

Comment: Would a pass-through query recognize the tables in the **local Access database** at the same time as it is querying tables in the remote SQL Server?

Comment: @zev, Have a look to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304323 , for pass-through query to sql server.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - No, pass-through queries only run in the scope of connection and cannot see the local database from which it was called. You can make-table from it: `SELECT * INTO [localtable] FROM [passthruQ]`

Comment: I created pass-through query in access.mdb to odbc connection to customers table in northwind database named RemoteTable, and created a local table in access.mdb  named LocalCustomer  then I created a query in access: insert into localCustomer
select customerid, companyname from remotecustomers.  The query works successfully, and this what the OP asks for..

Comment: @parfait. I did the query in access.mdb: SELECT * INTO localtable
FROM passthrouQ and a table is created named localtable with structure and data from remote table in sql server. passthrouQ  is a pass-through query for ODBC connection.